# Lit Web Component - Trying to select element

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit, native-web-component

I am trying to transform this element into a standard web component using Lit. (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_comparison.asp)

I totally new to Lit and to web components and am struggling to select elements from the shadow DOM. Right now, I am stuck with the var x inside the `initComparisons()` function. I am aware that the `document` object does not exist in the shadow dom and must be replaced by `renderRoot`, however, I am not sure either If I am selecting the elements the right way or what does replace the `window` object... Do you notice something wrong with this code? I am stuck at  the first lines of the `initComparisons()` function as `x` always returns null no matter what I do....

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you very much.

```
import {
  LitElement,
  css,
  html,
} from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/lit/dist@2/all/lit-all.min.js";

export class Comparator extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    baseImage: "",
    imageWidth: "",
    imageHeight: "",
    altImage: "",
  };

  // Define scoped styles right with your component, in plain CSS
  static styles = css`
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .img-comp-container {
      position: relative;
      height: 200px; /*should be the same height as the images*/
    }

    .img-comp-img {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .img-comp-img img {
      display: block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    .img-comp-slider {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 11;
      cursor: ew-resize;
      /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #2196f3;
      opacity: 0.7;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .border-slider {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 10;
      cursor: ew-resize;
      /*set the appearance of the slider:*/
      width: 5px;
      height: 130%;
      background-color: red;
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .border-slider::after {
      content: url("./separator.svg");
      position: absolute;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background: red;
      top: calc(50% - 15px);
      left: calc(50% - 15px);
    }
  `;

  constructor() {
    super();
    // Declare reactive defaults
    this.baseImage = "https://api.lorem.space/image/house?w=800&h=600";
    this.altImage = "https://api.lorem.space/image/house?w=800&h=600";
    this.imageWidth = "800px";
    this.imageHeight = "600px";
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.connectedCallback();
    this.initComparisons();
  }

  // Render the UI as a function of component state
  render() {
    return html`
      <div class="img-comp-container">
        <div class="img-comp-img">
          <img
            src="${this.baseImage}"
            width="${this.imageWidth}"
            height="${this.imageHeight}"
          />
        </div>
        <div id="img-comp-overlay" class="img-comp-img">
          <img
            src="${this.altImage}"
            width="${this.imageWidth}"
            height="${this.imageHeight}"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    `;
  }

  //HELPER FUCTIONS GO HERE
  initComparisons() {
    var x, i;
    /*find all elements with an "overlay" class:*/
    x = this.renderRoot.querySelector("#img-comp-overlay");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      /*once for each "overlay" element:
      pass the "overlay" element as a parameter when executing the compareImages function:*/
      compareImages(x[i]);
    }

    function compareImages(img) {
      var slider,
        img,
        clicked = 0,
        w,
        h;
      /*get the width and height of the img element*/
      w = img.offsetWidth;
      h = img.offsetHeight;
      /*set the width of the img element to 50%:*/
      img.style.width = w / 2 + "px";
      /*create slider:*/
      slider = this.renderRoot.createElement("DIV");
      slider.setAttribute("class", "border-slider");
      /*insert slider*/
      img.parentElement.insertBefore(slider, img);
      /*position the slider in the middle:*/
      slider.style.top = h / 2 - slider.offsetHeight / 2 + "px";
      slider.style.left = w / 2 - slider.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
      /*execute a function when the mouse button is pressed:*/
      slider.addEventListener("mousedown", slideReady);
      /*and another function when the mouse button is released:*/
      this.renderRoot.addEventListener("mouseup", slideFinish);
      /*or touched (for touch screens:*/
      slider.addEventListener("touchstart", slideReady);
      /*and released (for touch screens:*/
      window.addEventListener("touchend", slideFinish);
      function slideReady(e) {
        /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
        e.preventDefault();
        /*the slider is now clicked and ready to move:*/
        clicked = 1;
        /*execute a function when the slider is moved:*/
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", slideMove);
        window.addEventListener("touchmove", slideMove);
      }
      function slideFinish() {
        /*the slider is no longer clicked:*/
        clicked = 0;
      }
      function slideMove(e) {
        var pos;
        /*if the slider is no longer clicked, exit this function:*/
        if (clicked == 0) return false;
        /*get the cursor's x position:*/
        pos = getCursorPos(e);
        /*prevent the slider from being positioned outside the image:*/
        if (pos < 0) pos = 0;
        if (pos > w) pos = w;
        /*execute a function that will resize the overlay image according to the cursor:*/
        slide(pos);
      }
      function getCursorPos(e) {
        var a,
          x = 0;
        e = e.changedTouches ? e.changedTouches[0] : e;
        /*get the x positions of the image:*/
        a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
        /*calculate the cursor's x coordinate, relative to the image:*/
        x = e.pageX - a.left;
        /*consider any page scrolling:*/
        x = x - window.pageXOffset;
        return x;
      }
      function slide(x) {
        /*resize the image:*/
        img.style.width = x + "px";
        /*position the slider:*/
        slider.style.left = img.offsetWidth - slider.offsetWidth / 2 + "px";
      }
    }
  }
}

customElements.define("image-compare", Comparator);
```

Comment: The source is all vanilla JavaScript. Then what does Lit add?? Wrap it in a vanilla JavaScript Web Component, saves you 16KB .. and you learn Web Components instead of a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`connectedCallback()` is likely too early to call `this.initComparison()` as the elements might not have been populated within the shadowroot. That happens on first render so you can grab those elements in [`firstUpdated()`](https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/#firstupdated) instead.